# Rails nested_form inside nested_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I have the following models and relations:

```
Rate fields
  t.string :type
  t.string :name

class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_rate_requests
end

CategoryRateRequests fields
  t.date :date_from
  t.date :date_to

class CategoryRateRequests < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rate
  has_many :category_rates
end

CategoryRate 
  t.integer :room_category_id
  t.integer :new_rate_id
  t.integer :category_rate_request_id
  t.integer :amount

class CategoryRate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rate
  belongs_to :category_rate_request
  belongs_to :room_category
end
```

And I'm trying to have a nested_form inside a nested_form

```
= nested_form_for @rate do |f|
  = label_tag :name, t('rates.new.name'), class: 'grey h2'
  = f.text_field(:name, required: true, class: 'form-input form-control full-width-input')
  = f.fields_for :category_rate_request do |request|
    = request.text_field(:date_from,  class: 'date-input form-control start-date-input', type: 'text', 'data-provide': 'datepicker', placeholder: t('common.date_from'))
    = request.text_field(:date_to, class: 'date-input form-control end-date-input', type: 'text', 'data-provide': 'datepicker', placeholder: t('common.date_to'))
    = request.fields_for :category_rate, do |u|
      = u.number_field(:price, class: "form-control", placeholder:  placeholder)
```

Overall this is the format. It has more things, but to not include too much unnecesary information I omitted some fields of the form.

But I get the following error

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 690ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
>
> SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block ;
>   _slim_controls2 = request.fields_for :new_category_rate, do |u|; 
>                                                                ^ /project/app/views/new_rates/_category_rate_requests.html.slim:61:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input:

That line marked in red is:

`= request.fields_for :new_category_rate, do |u|`

Is there any way I can have the attributes of all three models in one form? In the `Rate` form more precisely.

Comment: Not enough code. Please post your parameters method for model A (should be something like `def model_params` where `model` is the name of your model.

Comment: Please provide snippet of the code and the error log.

Comment: You have an extra comma in the erroring line. Change it to: `= request.fields_for :new_category_rate do |u|`

Comment: Thank you, this was it. Can u put in an answer so that I can mark this as resolved?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've now made it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(copied from comment)*

You have an extra comma in the erroring line. Change it to:

```
= request.fields_for :new_category_rate do |u|
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to use that gem for a particular reason, but I think it hasn't been updated for too long for use it.

I use [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon), and with simple form you just need to do:

```
simple_form_for @a do |f|
  f.simple_fields_for :b do |b_f|
    b_f.simple_fields_for :c do |c_f|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

You can use `link_to_add_association` and `link_to_remove_association` in a very friendly way too.