# Dynamically generate copies partial form based on user selection in a nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to create a form that will generate copies of a nested form depending on a user's selection. I have 3 models: Visualizations, which has_many Rows, which has_many Panes.

I want to be able to allow the user to click a small dropdown menu that will generate a row and then select 1, 2, or 3 panes. Depending on their selection, this will generate the form of their choice from a render.

[here is an example where a user chose 3 panes (3 upload boxes for images) with just styled divs in place of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gMBU.png)

For starters. I know I would need to change up my controller a bit, but I'm not sure how to do that with a nested form since in every example I've seen so far, you need to predetermine how many times you would "build" a nested model form (not sure if that is the correct terminology). I'm not sure how to make that part dynamic.

Here is what I mean:

```html
//visualization_controller.rb

def new
    @visualization = Visualization.new
    rows = @visualization.rows.build
    panes = rows.panes.build
  end
```

here is an example of the render that would be called if the usr wanted to generate a row with just 1 Pane:

```html
  <div class="medium-12 columns one_box_wrapper first" style="display:none">
    <%= f.fields_for :rows, Row.new do |r| %>
    <%= r.label :rowtitle %>
    <%= r.text_field :rowtitle %>
    <div class="nested" style="display:inline-block">
          <%= r.fields_for :panes, Pane.new do |p| %>
            <%= p.label :text %>
            <%= p.text_field :text %>
            <div class="mehv">
              <img id="img_prev" width=300 height=300 src="#" alt="your image" class="img-thumbnail hidden"/> <br/>
              <span class="meh">
                Upload Pane Image<%= p.file_field :pane_photo, id: "pane_photo" %>
              </span>
              <%= p.hidden_field :pane_photo_cache %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Is this possible in rails? I feel like javascript would come into play but I don't think you are allowed to render server-side code through JS.

I feel a bit in over my head with this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I ended up using cocoon gem as it seems to have made my life a lot easier however.. I can't get the visualizations to all display on the index page! I'm not sure what the issue is.. The cover Title and Image show up but nothing else does!

```html
//schema.rb

  create_table "panes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "row_id",     null: false
    t.text    "text"
    t.string  "pane_photo"
  end

  create_table "rows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "visualization_id", null: false
    t.string  "rowtitle"
  end

  create_table "visualizations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title",       null: false
    t.string "cover_image"
  end
```

```html
//controller.rb

class VisualizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authorize_user, except: [:index, :show]
  helper_method :resource

  def index
    @visualizations = Visualization.all
    @visualization = Visualization.new
  end

  def new
    @visualization = Visualization.new
    rows = @visualization.rows.build
    panes = rows.panes.build
  end

  def create
    @visualization = Visualization.new(visualization_params)

    if @visualization.save
      redirect_to edit_visualization_path(@visualization)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @visualizations = Visualization.all
    @visualization = Visualization.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected

  def visualization_params
    params.require(:visualization).permit(:title, :cover_image, rows_attributes: [:visualization_id, :rowtitle, panes_attributes:[:text, :pane_photo]])
  end
```

```html
//index.html

<div class="visual_wrap text-center">
  <ul class="no-bullet text-center">
    <% @visualizations.each do |visualization| %>
    <li class="text-center">
      <div class="row visualization text-center">
        <%= image_tag visualization.cover_image.to_s, id: "visualization_image", class: "output_image" %>
        <p class="visualization_title"><%= visualization.title %></p>
        <a href="#" id="visualization_link"><p>+</p></a>
      </div>
      <div class="placeholder">
        <% visualization.rows.each do |row| %>
          <%= row.rowtitle %>
            <% row.panes.each do |p| %>
              <%= p.text %>
              <%= image_tag p.pane_photo.to_s, id: "pane_image", class: "output_image" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```html
//new.html.erb

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<div class="try">
  <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
    <ul class="breadcrumbs">
      <%= form_for @visualization, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
      <li><a href="#" class="preview button secondary">Preview</a></li>
      <li><div class="separating-bar">|</div>
        <li><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="save button secondary"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cover_image text-center">
      <div class="row pre_img_prev">
        <div class="gray_bar"></div>
        <div class="img_prev">
          <img id="img_preview" src="#" alt="your image" class="img-thumbnail hidden text-center"/>
          <input type="text" name="visualization[title]" id="visualization[title]" class="inputtext" />
          <label for="visualization[title]" id="text_preview">+ Add Title</label>
          <div class="trash-can_title">
            <a href="#" id="trash-can_title"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="visualization[cover_image]" id="visualization_cover_image" class="inputfile" />
        <label for="visualization_cover_image">+ Add Cover Image</label>
        <%= f.hidden_field :cover_image_cache %>
        <div class="trash-can_cover">
          <a href="#" id="trash-can_cover"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row linkstest">
    <div class="rows">
      <%= f.fields_for :rows, Row.new do |task| %>
        <%= render 'row_fields', f: task %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association "Add Row", f, :rows %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need really need JS except to make it more "snappy". I think what you are looking for are Nested Forms.

Take a look at [RaisCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) it's a bit outdated but it's a good foundation.

You might want to look into [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to help you create the new fields dynamically.

[Rails nested_form inside nested_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977301/rails-nested-form-inside-nested-form)

**Update**

If you don't want to use Javascript at all, you need to make an extra request to the controller to tell it to initialize (build) the rows and panes for you so that it renders the empty fields in the view.
For example:

```
def new
  @visualization = Visualization.new
  num_rows = params[:num_rows]
  num_rows.each { @visualization.rows.build }
end
```

You would also need to have the number of panes in each row, so the parameter would have to be inside the row attributes, e.g. `params[:visualization][:rows][0][:num_panes]`, and using that parameter you initialize the panes in the row. It's probably best to put that logic in a Factory service.

However if you create the empty fields using JS you can save yourself from making that extra request and all that logic. This is because Rails will automatically initialize (build) the rows and panes if you give it the right attributes, such as:

```
{
  visualization: {
    rows_attributes: {
      # These are the attributes from an existing record
      0: {
        id: 39,
        panes_attributes: {
          0: {
            id: 992
          }
        }
      },
      # This is a new set of attributes for a new record
      # passed by the fields generated by cocoon where xxx
      # and yyy are random numbers
      xxxx: {
        panes_attributes: {
          yyyy: {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then all you need to do in your controller is:

```
def new
  # visualization_params are the permitted attributes
  @visualization = Visualization.new(visualization_params)
end
```

Comment: I did look at that actually and am considering it.. Maybe just on creation of my visualization, redirect to edit page to add rows?

Comment: Oops didn't finish my comment. I meant to ask why I don't really need JS? How would I be able to render a new field without it? Does cocoon handle that?

Comment: Updated my answer, might take a moment to get accepted hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm just immensely confused by the javascript there. But from what you're saying it sounds like it would save me an immense headache.

I'm not sure how I would generate empty fields using JS since those fields are erb?

Apologies for taking so much of your time.

Comment: The Cocoon gem offers the JS to generate the empty fields, it basically renders the fields html as a string for Javascript to use. You should watch the Railscast linked in the answer, I feel that would answer most of your questions. If you still have questions dont' hesitate to another comment

Comment: Ahh I think I'm so close! I edited my above problem if you could possibly look it over.

Comment: Could you show add the content of the form, i.e. `new.html.erb`

Comment: I'm sorry it may be a bit convoluted as I've had to do certain crazy stuff to make it look nice (the cover image part at least).

Comment: Ahh, I get it. So the problem is that you can't see the rows and panes in the listing or in the form? If it's in the listing look at the browser html source code, maybe no rows are being saved

Comment: Crap! You're right the Row and Pane attributes are not saving.

Comment: It unfortunately looks like it is saving the first pane.. but any additional panes that are generated are not saved..Any ideas?

Comment: If multiple rows are being saved, just make sure you have similar code for the panes. Take a look at the log and double check the parameters that are being sent in the http request

Comment: Multiple rows are not being saved. Only 1 row and 1 pane from the initial code... Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: It's hard to help you debug, my best recommendation is that you take your time to understand how nested forms work in Rails, do a google search for more resources online. The important pieces are "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in the model, ".permit" attributes in the controller, and making sure that your HTML form is sending the attributes in the proper structure.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to get back to this! I figured out my issue and it was a dumb one. My form_for visualization started within a div while some of the subsequent fields were outside of that div. I just needed to move my `<%= form_for @visualization %>`  to the outermost div and it works!


Just out of curiosity do you know of a way to modify the link_to_add_association so that depending on if someone chooses 1, 2, or 3, it will automatically generate that many children? I was thinking a render.

Again, thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Haven't looked into cocoon for a while. Don't know if theres a baked in feature. You could just css hide the cocoon button and add your own control that fake clicks the cocoon button. It's a hack obviously, but might get you on the way to a better solution. Happy coding